# Reading and updating a csv file through paralell sessions: Is there a convenient way to avoid a "lost update"?

Tags: powershell, concurrency

Let there be multiple PowerShell sessions processing the following task using one centralized csv file: 
**Edit**: To be more precise, those sessions are distributed and cannot communicate within the same memory.

1. Read the csv file to memory (`Import-Csv`)
2. Do some time-consuming work
3. Write changes to the csv representation in memory
4. Write changes back to the csv file, updating one dedicated row per session (`Export-Csv`)

To prevent a lost update scenario from happening here, i thought of the following possibilities:

1. we make sure that only one PowerShell session goes through step 1 to 4 at a time. (Locking the file, denying access for other processes)
2. because in this case each PowerShell session takes care for its own row, it could be sufficient if we could "update" only one row in the file as an atomic operation. 
   However the `Export-Csv` cmdlet can overwrite a complete file or append rows and is afaik not capable of updating only one specific row without rewriting those from its perspective unchanged rows, where data could be lost.

I appreciate any thougths or hints which could lead to a **secure** (no data-loss through lost update possible) and **fast** (not locking the file for too long) solution.

Comment: Do you control all the callers? Or are they autonomous/independent processes trying to solve similar problems using the same file for storage? If you're in control, why not have a single process that takes care of the file I/O, and then you can have multiple other processes doing the time-consuming work concurrently? If it's the latter = find a better database engine than a CSV file :)

Comment: i think that csv files are not "designed" for parallel write access, thus your concerns about potential data loss. Maybe you can use something else? E.g. : parallel thread write output into their own files; and once they all finished, you combine them together. option 2) upload CSV file into any database and then your thread with safely read/write into DB

Comment: [1] use PoSh jobs & have the main caller request the info & then write each to the same csv file. ///// [2] take a look at synchronized variables. >>> Hashtable.Synchronized(Hashtable) Method (System.Collections) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.synchronized?view=net-6.0

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen they are processes trying to solve similar problems using the same file for storage. I agree with you, i would prefer a database engine taking care of those old problems for me too, but i can only use files. maybe i can split the csv into multiple files, so that each process can get its own file, like MikeSh suggested...

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i guess that would work if they were on the same host and could access the same memory for "coordination".

I updated the question to be more precise.

Comment: @Bobbey - then have the processes save their info to a local file ... and have the master script grab those files & merge them as desired.